# Why do these two linq queries return different numbers of results?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

In a web application that I work with I found a slow piece of code that I wanted to speed up a bit.  Original code below:

```
foreach (Guid g in SecondaryCustomersIds)
{
    var Customer = (from d in Db.CustomerRelationships

                    join c in Db.Customers on
                    d.PrimaryCustomerId equals c.CustomerId

                    where c.IsPrimary == true && d.SecondaryCustomerId == g
                    select c).Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
   //Add this customer to a List<>
}
```

I thought it might be faster to load this all into a single query, so I attempted to rewrite it as the query below:

```
var Customers = (from d in Db.CustomerRelationships

                 join c in Db.Customers on
                 d.PrimaryCustomerId equals c.CustomerId

                 where c.IsPrimary == true && SecondaryCustomersIds.Contains(d.SecondaryCustomerId)
                 select c).Distinct();
```

Which is indeed faster, but now the new query returns fewer records than the first.  It seems to me that these two chunks of code are doing the same thing and should return the same number of records.  Can anyone see why they would not?  What am I missing here?

Comment: May it be that you are having duplicates in the 1st one? Have you tried doing a `.Distinct` to the final list to which you add all the customers?

Comment: No, sorry I should have mentioned that.  Getting the distinct of the final list returns the same count, so there are no duplicates being returned.

Comment: How is `SecondaryCustomersIds` defined?

Comment: It is a `List<Guid>` that is populated using a method that is probably beyond the scope of this question.  I can say that the same `SecondaryCustomersIds` is being used for both pieces of code.

Comment: What about a benchmarking here? it would give you the answer but may not explain why.

Comment: If you have any duplicates within `SecondaryCustomersIds`, the first query would contain extra values, and calling `Distinct()` on the resulting list would not take the extras out unless your `Customer` objects implement some equality check that is not just checking to see if the references are equal. Do you know how those objects implement `Equals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for the first query to add a null object to the list (`SingleOrDefault` will return the default for the type, or `null` in this case, if it can't find a matching entity). Thus, for every Customer without a matching relationship, you could be adding a null object to that `List<>,` which would increase the count.

Answer (score 0):

In your first scenario, does your final `List<Customers>` have duplicates?

You're calling `Distinct`, but also looping, which means you're not doing `Distinct` on your entire collection.

Your second example is calling `Distinct` on the entire collection.

Comment: @Noctis while I feel that this should be a comment more than an answer (too speculative), we both submitted our posts at the same time so I won't ask for royalties.

Comment: Added this as a comment, but just to clarify, selecting `Distinct` from the final `List<Customers>` does not change the number of records.

Comment: It is the same as the comment, true, but I didn't see it at the time I was answering